# How to use Font Awesome 5 with Svelte/Sappe

Tags: font-awesome, svelte, sapper

I am writing a Server Side Rendered app with Svelte/Sapper and I am having trouble using Font Awesome fonts.

I am using the following to load the font:

```
<script>
  import Icon from "svelte-awesome";
  import { faTimes } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faTimes";
</script>

<Icon data={faTimes} />
```

The error I am seeing is:
" is not a valid SSR component. You may need to review your build config to ensure that dependencies are compiled, rather than imported as pre-compiled modules"

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure that your import is correct? Can you try without the curly braces? Please check this REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/9905305c60bc46d99b6c52f1736eaba8?version=3.23.0

Comment: With straight Svelte this works.  With the server-side rendering of Sapper, however, it does not work.

Comment: any fixes? same issue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I landed on this page looking for ways to import just the FontAwesome CSS into Svelte without any additional components or dependencies. Turns out that with Svelte this is just as simple as with plain HTML: Get the FontAwesome CSS (e.g. via package manager, CDN, or download) and add it to the HTML `<head>` section.

1. I like to install it via npm to maintain its version together with all other depencies:
   `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`
2. After installing, just add the stylesheet (from the @fortawesome directory inside node_modules) to the `<head>` section of `app.html`.

```html
<head>
    ...
    <link href="./../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
</head>
```

3. Use FontAwesome icons in your Svelte components, e.g. `<i class="fa-regular fa-lightbulb">`

Comment: Note you also need the js. I choose to import both in `main.js`: `import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';` `import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';`

Comment: Should it work also after `npm run build`? Because in my case it does not

Answer (score 8):

After spending 5 hours trying to figure it out, finally here's the simplest way to use Fontawesome icons in Sveltekit (also works in **production** environment):

1. Install the fontawesome package

   ```
   npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
   ```
2. Import the css file containing all icons in the component or page where you need it. (Can also be imported in `+layout.ts` to apply to multiple pages)

   ```js
   import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'
   ```
3. You can now use your icons in the simple classical way:

   ```html
   <i class="fa-regular fa-lightbulb">
   ```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For svelete-aweome, the import should look as follows in Sapper:

```
  import Icon from 'svelte-awesome/components/Icon';
```

Comment: The OP isn't intending to rely on third party packages